# PHP features enabled/disabled depending on user

Tags: php

I am currently writing a website using php as my server side scripting language. I have it already working so that the current user is stored using cookies/sessions depending on the user preference.

I want people to be able to view other peoples profile pages, but obviously features will be disabled if the profile page isn't their own. How would I go about this? Should I be using sessions or something else? This will obviously have to work so when the link to someone else's profile page is clicked, it remembers that the 'profile.php' will have to disable some features.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a session variable if this are like 2 or 3 specific features that need to be disabled. Or you can create a table on your database called privileges or something. and there add boolean fields for each feature that can or cannot be enabled. and every time you make a Query you do a if condition if(privile['select'] == TRUE)

Comment: thanks, it was more like Facebook style so you can click on other peoples profile, and stuff like editing personal details would be disabled. I guess you would just set a session variable which remember the last profile link was clicked, and check that against the currently logged in user?

Comment: Do you have a Database for this right? it's simple. Create a table called user_permission and for each user when registering set a default permission. that they can later modify. and on your profile.php you set conditions like if(edit==True) { // show enabled  } else { // Show disabled }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common scenario, and here is a pattern that I integrate when running into situations like this.

Assuming you are using sessions, when a user logs in, set:

```
$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
```

When a user logs out, set:

```
$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = false;
```

Then you can create a helper function that returns a boolean like this:

```
function is_user_logged_in() {
    return $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'];
}
```

Then, throughout your code you can conditionally show items based on the return value of the helper function.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //show the logout button if current user is logged in
    echo "<button class='logout'>Logout</button>";
} else {
    //show the login button if current user is not logged in
    echo "<button class='login'>Login</button>";
}
```

WordPress uses a helper function by the same name: **[is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)**.

Answer (score 0):

You must identify who is the one who log-in...

Here is the system flow

If the user log-in store the unique identity of that user to `Session`

(i.e `$_Session['UniqueID'] == UserID` )

So if the user click the profile of other user it will compare if the

```
$_Session['UniqueID'] == ClickedUserID
```

If `true` then enable features
If `false` then disable features

I hope it will help you.